# Testing django mail and attachment return empty

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to test mails with attachment, I'm attaching the files something like this:

```
# snippet of send_pdf_mail
mail = EmailMessage(
        subject=subject,
        body=message,
        from_email=from_email,
        to=recipient_list,
    )
    dynamic_template_data.update({'subject': subject})
    mail.content_subtype = 'html'
    mail.dynamic_template_data = dynamic_template_data
    mail.template_id = dynamic_template_id

    if attachment:
        attachment.open()
        mail.attach(basename(attachment.name), attachment.read(), guess_type(attachment.name)[0])
        attachment.close()
    return mail.send(fail_silently=False)
```

then my test is something like this:

```
    f = open('tests/test.pdf', 'rb')
    user.pdf.save('test.pdf', File(f))
    f.close()

    send_pdf_mail(user)
    self.assertEqual(len(mail.outbox), 1)
    self.assertEqual(mail.outbox[0].to[0], user.email)
```

But when I try to check if there are attachment via:

```
print(mail.outbox[0].attachments)
```

It returns an empty list so I'm not sure why but I tested the code and I can confirm that this indeed includes an attachment when sending an e-mail.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use *EmailMultiAlternatives* instead of *EmailMessage*

In this case you can attack file without any problems

```
email_message = EmailMultiAlternatives(
    subject="subject",
    to="to_email",
)
html_email: str = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context)
email_message.attach_alternative(html_email, 'text/html')
if file_path:
    email_message.attach_file(file_path, mimetype="file mimetype")
email_message.send()
```

So you need to create **EmailMultiAlternatives** instance and via **attach_file()** method add a path to file.
Also need to provide **mimetype** of the file. For example for pdf file will be **mimetype="application/pdf"**